# Can we implement a stack, queue, linkedlist, or tree in which every operations are in o(1) time?

Tags: data-structures

Just expecting this question in my next job interview and want to make a good impression.

Comment: Sure, if you use suitable definitions of "every operation" and "tree". If you choose something useful, maybe not. So what are your operations, and what kind of tree would you like?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a job interview, for this question, I think the purpose of this blur question is to let you ask them questions to see your knowledge and skills.

You can ask questions like:

What operations are most concerned? Add/delete record? edit? search?

Probably testing your konwledge about the differences among these data structures.